# How to show the questions webpart on a page?

Tags: survey, list-form-web-part

I am using the sp 2013 survey list. I have add 4 questions. I would like to show the questions on the homepage of the sharepoint site. I tried the pageviewer webpart, but it is ugly with scrollbars. When I did some research I found this:

with the querystring you see no masterpage and only the questions:
[image]

I add also the querystring contents=1 to show the webparts. I see the questions are inside a ListFormWebPart. Is it possible to add this webpart programmatically on a page?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can definitely add this on home page, however you need little SharePoint designer skills for this. You can copy existing newform.aspx code and add it on home page aspx inside sharepoint designer. However, you might want to see its behavior regarding redirection on survey submit action.

Another solution is, You can go ahead with page viewer webpart, for scrolls you can adjust the page viewer webpart height in web-part properties. Will little trial you can get exact height where your survey questions becomes visible in single view.

Comment: yes I am trying now the solution to build it in a page viewer webpart. Is it possible to set the height perfect without scrollbars programatically.